# IE9 Compatibility : jQuery ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to POST a form from my website to a server (not same domain).
Everything is working fine with Chrome, Firefox and IE10+, but I have to make it work with IE9 too.

Here's my code

```
$("#sendform").click(function() {

 // Content
  var infosForm = {};
        infosForm.firstname = $('input[name=firstname]')[0].value;
        infosForm.name = $('input[name=name]')[0].value;
        infosForm.phone = $('input[name=tel]')[0].value;
        infosForm.mail = $('input[name=mail]')[0].value;
        infosForm.commentaire = $('textarea[name=comment]')[0].value;
        var isChecked = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();
        if (isChecked == "on")
        {
            infosForm.isNewsletter = "on";
        }
        else
        {
            infosForm.isNewsletter = "off";
        }

     $.ajax({
      url:'http://my.website.com/form.ashx',
      type:'post',
      data:infosForm,
      cache:false, //normaly this is quite useless since it's a post, but It's known to help with IE... still not.
      crossDomain:true,

        //showing feedback          
success:function(){
  $("#contact form").hide(); 
  $("#contact form").fadeIn('slow').html("<p>Success</p>");
  //trackEvent();
      },
 error:function(){   
  $("#contact form").hide(); 
  $("#contact form").fadeIn('slow').html("<p>Error</p>");
      }
    });
});
```

According to fiddler, it seems like IE9 isn't sending any request and going straight to showing the error message.

Note : jQuery 1.8.3 is used here.

Comment: You need to do a little debugging. There's nothing apparent, to me, that is wrong, especially for IE9. Look at IE's developer tools and see if you see any specific errors (like a network error, or syntax error).

Comment: I've tried debugging before coming to sof, but IE sends no error message at all.

Comment: Take a look here (comment 3): http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12097

Comment: Hi, I tried the trick mentioned here, with no success, I guess since I use a more recent jQuery version (1.8.3), this bug is corrected and we have to look for something else.

Answer (score 1):

IE8/9 don't support XmlHttpRequest object used by jQuery, hence it is needed to use the object XDomainRequest.

Such plugin : [xdr.js](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js) will make it work.

Be aware of [XDomainRequest own limitations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

In this line

> var isChecked = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val()

semicolon (;) is missing.

Comment: I added the missing semicolon. All my apologies for letting such errors in my code. Yet it changed nothing to the situation.

Comment: Semicolons aren't required in JavaScript, especially here